# Scrolling create rows in IE9 on drag & drop elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

https://jsfiddle.net/hjcsnrs3/1/

I have created above fiddle to explain my problem. I am using jQuery sortable for drag-drop elements horizontally. Works fine in Chrome/FF. But in IE, especially IE9, whenever I drag and element, it drops to next row. Each drag drop create new row.

```
$( function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    items: "> div",
    opacity: 0.8,
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    helper: "original",
    revert: true,
    axis: "x"
  });
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: You might want to consider using an alternative staging solution as jsfiddle does not support IE9 and I can't test/debug the result if the result doesn't even show up.

Comment: I suspect this might actually be a cross browser CSS issue

Comment: not able to replicate your issue, even with jquery-ui-1.12.1 on IE8... maybe you missed something from your fiddle? Just asking.

Comment: drop IE9 support

Comment: as @deblocker mentioned earlier, this issue is not reproducable in our system. I have installed new virtual win xp which had ie 7 and tested your code on it. surprisingly it works flawless in ie7

Comment: works perfectly in IE9

Answer (score 0):

I made a local copy in check on IE every version. It works fine in all version except IE5. IE5 has the same issue as you have mentioned.

[CSS element>element Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) is supported below IE7.
For element>element to work in IE8 and earlier, a `<!DOCTYPE>` must be declared.

change it from:

```
#sortable >div { float: left; }
```

to:

```
.ui-sortable-handle{float:left;}
```

**[Updates Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/hjcsnrs3/2/)**